# How can I find all the volumes mounted by Time Machine

Tags: macos

I try to find all the volumes mounted by Time Machine.

I found the `tmutil destinationinfo` which list all Time Machine volumes. If those are mounted I can find the local path by looking at the `Mount Point` entry.

This works well for external HDD. If a network backup is used, I saw that Time Machine mount another volume (generally named: "Time Machine Backup"), and I'm unable to find a command or some api which list this volume.

So, is a command, api which can list all the volumes which contains Time Machine backups?

Answer (score 0):

`tmutil destinationinfo` lists the network drives as well. What are you seeing?

```
$ tmutil destinationinfo
====================================================
Name          : TMBackup
Kind          : Network
URL           : afp://TimeMachine@camel(TimeMachine)._afpovertcp._tcp.local/TMBackup
Mount Point   : /Volumes/TMBackup
ID            : XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: I see this, and the mount disk (/Volumes/TMBackup) contains a Sparse Disk Image Bundle, which is mounted by Time Machine in /Volumes/Time Machine Backups, in my case. I want to find a way to also get the volume in which the Sparse Disk Image Bundle is mounted.